# ACF and Wordpress - Find all posts from which a post has been related?

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have a number of different post types attached to various posts of type `person` through various fields (for example: contributors, editors, proofreading). I was wondering if there is any way to find all the posts attached to each `person` in reverse, or is it necessary to query every possible relationship field one by one?

Basically, I'm wondering if there's any kind of wp_query that can be built that results in 'Find every post that post X has been related to'.

Answer (score 0):

If you've used the relationship field for ACF you can do a reverse query. ACF has a tutorial on their website that covers the details - https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/querying-relationship-fields/